# How to make Woocommerce Upsells and Cross-Sells manually sortable

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

This seems so simple, but I'm stuck. Hoping someone can help.

I'm trying to make the cross-sell and upsell select2 boxes sortable on the edit product page, and as I was testing it in console it did add the sorting handles, but when saving the product, it reverted to alphabetical order.

```
$("ul.select2-selection__rendered").sortable({
      containment: 'parent'
});
```

On front end, I believe I could achieve manual order by just using the sorting filter as 'none'

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_upsells_orderby', 'filter_woocommerce_upsells_orderby', 10, 1 );

function filter_woocommerce_upsells_orderby( $orderby ){
    return "none";
};
```

But how to best achieve manual ordering on the edit product page (and on front end)? Surely there must be an easier way to enable sorting.

Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Managed to figure it out in the end. It was just an incomplete js issue. I wasn't properly setting up the 'sortable' property for the fields. After I did, the order was saved properly.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
        
    $( 'select.wc-product-search.enhanced' ).each( function() {
        
        //Add sortable attribute to select2 product fields (upsell and cross-sell)
        $(this).attr('data-sortable', true);
        
        let $select = $(this);
        let $list   = $(this).next( '.select2-container' ).find( 'ul.select2-selection__rendered' );
        
        $list.sortable({
            placeholder : 'ui-state-highlight select2-selection__choice',
            forcePlaceholderSize: true,
            items       : 'li:not(.select2-search__field)',
            tolerance   : 'pointer',
            stop: function() {
                $( $list.find( '.select2-selection__choice' ).get().reverse() ).each( function() {
                    var id     = $( this ).data( 'data' ).id;
                    var option = $select.find( 'option[value="' + id + '"]' )[0];
                    $select.prepend( option );
                } );
            }
        });
    
    });
    
});
```

And like said above, on the front-end to make sorting respect the saved order from the field, I set `orderby` property to 'none'

Comment: Thank you so much for sharing. This helped me. I too was struggling with finding a way to custom order cross-sells. In my custom code I am grabbing the cross sell ids by getting the _crosssell_ids meta, but as you said WooCommerce automatically orders that alphabetically. You would think that this would be something WooCommerce would do by default. Or at the very least, order it based on the way you select the items, and NOT alphabetically. That feels much more arbitrary.